# Listen on INSERT/UPDATE of MS SQL Server using Node-RED/node.js

Tags: node.js, sql-server, triggers, node-red, sqlclr

I am looking for a way to get data inserted into an MS SQL Server table (2014 Express) to Node-RED or node.js without polling a table.

My previous research led me to SQL Servers Service Broker. Unfortunately the Service Broker is not available for Express Version of MSSQL Server 2014.

Is there any other way to listen on MSSQL table changes using Node-RED/node.js without the useage of middleware (e.g. writing a .NET service)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the requisite access to the SQL Server database you could use a SQL AFTER INSERT TRIGGER to run an external process which signals node-red but I believe polling the table would be much simpler